# .net core controller action sharing values using HttpContext

Tags: asp.net-core, httpcontext

I've two controller action in my application ,  FirstAction and SecondAction.
When the FirstAction is called , I want to store a data and want to reuse in SecondAction.
I've tried HttpContext and cannot get value in SecondAction.  It always retrun null .

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> FirstAction()
        {
                HttpContext.Items.Add("Key1", myValue1);
                HttpContext.Items.Add("Key2", myValue2);
        }

 public async Task<IActionResult> SecondAction()
        {
               var _value1 =  HttpContext.Items["Key1"]?.ToString();
               var _value2 =  HttpContext.Items["Key2"]?.ToString();
        }
```

Is there any better way for such kind of scenairo ?

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use HttpContext? Why not store the data in a dictionary<string,string> in the global scope of the controller?

Comment: @jawsofdoom , yes , if it's a better way , please post as answer or give me some reference .

Comment: The HTTP Context refers to the current request. You need to store the data in `HttpContext.Session`.

Answer (score 1):

`HttpContext.Items` stores data for a single request only. [From the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1#httpcontextitems) on state management :

> The HttpContext.Items collection is used to store data while processing a single request. The collection's contents are discarded after a request is processed.

You can [store data in session state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1#session-state) to preserve it from one request to the next, as long as a user's session is active. You'd have to [configure session storage first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1#configure-session-state). The in-memory option is only valid for a single server. Database or Redis storage are suitable for server farms used eg in load balancing scenarios.

The docs show [how to set and read session state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1#set-and-get-session-values) using strongly typed methods, eg :

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString(SessionKeyName, "The Doctor");
HttpContext.Session.SetInt32(SessionKeyAge, 773);
```

and

```
var name = HttpContext.Session.GetString(SessionKeyName);
var age = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32(SessionKeyAge);
```

Comment: When it expires. You specify the timeout in the configuration.

Comment: I've searched for better solution , such as using ViewData,TempData , Cookies.  
Is `HttpContext.Session` better solution for such kind of scenario ?

Comment: @StevenSann, no, not better, using of session is potentially great overhead for your webapp. So, it depends on lifetime of a state you want to persist. In case of short lifecycle objects, like yours, TempData would be better.

Comment: @Ryan , in my example, there are only two Actions.  Later , I can have more like 3 or 5 Actions , so it cannot be considered as short lifecycle , right ?

Comment: @StevenSann TempData can be used in the subsequent request, after that it will be invalid. Since you may need to use the value in the next 3 or 5 actions, I would recommend use session.